# How to loop through multiple cell values on VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to simplify the following code into one loop only. How can I do that?

```
 Dim VARIANTE as LONG

 For Each cell In Sheets("Libro2").Range("C1:C30000")

      If cell.Value = Sheets("Libro1").Range("AA1") Then
         VARIANTE = cell.Row
        Sheets("Libro2").Range("Z" & VARIANTE) = 1
    End If
 Next

 For Each cell In Sheets("Libro2").Range("C1:C30000")

      If cell.Value = Sheets("Libro1").Range("AA2") Then
         VARIANTE = cell.Row
        Sheets("Libro2").Range("Z" & VARIANTE) = 1
    End If
 Next

  For Each cell In Sheets("Libro2").Range("C1:C30000")

      If cell.Value = Sheets("Libro1").Range("AA3") Then
         VARIANTE = cell.Row
        Sheets("Libro2").Range("Z" & VARIANTE) = 1
    End If
 Next

[...] 'and so on, and so forth
```

Here is something I've tried, but it didn't work, of course. Maybe there is a solution out there, but I couldn't find it because of language issues.

```
  For Each cell In Sheets("Libro2").Range("C1:C30000")

      If cell.Value = Sheets("Libro1").Range("AA1:AA50") Then
         VARIANTE = cell.Row
        Sheets("Libro2").Range("Z" & VARIANTE) = 1
    End If
 Next
```

Comment: `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Libro1").Range("AA1:AA50"), cell.Value) > 0 Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is what so brilliantly BigBen, in only one sentence, answered my question inmediately, and which I'm enterily grateful.

```
  For Each cell In Sheets("Libro2").Range("C1:C30000")
     If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("concat").Range("AD20951:AD20956"), cell.Value) > 0 Then
     VARIANTE = cell.Row
     Sheets("Libro2").Range("Z" & VARIANTE) = 1
     End If
  Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub testLoopCols()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, shL As Worksheet, rngAA As Range, arrC, arrZ, i As Long, mtch
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
 Set shL = Sheets("Libro1")
 arrC = sh.Range("C1:C30000").value  'place the range in an array for faster iteration
 arrZ = sh.Range("Z1:Z30000").value  'place the range to return (using an array)
 Set rngAA = shL.Range("AA1:AA50")   'the range where to match each cell of C:C range
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrC)
    mtch = Application.match(arrC(i, 1), rngAA, 0) 'match in a range = much faster than in an array...
    If Not IsError(mtch) Then        'if a match exists:
        arrZ(i, 1) = 1               'place 1 in the final array
    End If
 Next i
 'drop the processed array result, at once:
 sh.Range("Z1:Z30000").value = arrZ
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: @Santos Lee Did you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it solve your problem?

Comment: couldn't make it work

Comment: What dies that mean?